# How i can move my root web to be defined as a sub-site inside the same site collection

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, configuration, sub-site

I have a site collection of type team site inside my On-Premise sharepoint enterprise server 2013. Now inside the team site root web i have added 2 lists (Discussion board + Issue list).
**Now i want to move my root web and its lists to be inside a sub-site inside the current site collection. and to create a blank root web...**

so can anyone advice which approach i can use?
Now i try saving the root web as template. then i create a new sub-site based on the site template.. but the problem is that the list items inside the new sub-site got new values for the system generated fields such as Created,Modified,Createdby & ModifiedBy... while i need to preserve the original values for the lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve metadata, you're probably in the land of migration tools already. There are several out there such as [Content Matrix from Metalogix](https://www.metalogix.com/product/content-matrix), [DocAve from AvePoint](https://www.avepoint.com/au/office-365-and-sharepoint-migration/), [ShareGate](https://en.share-gate.com/sharepoint-migration) and [many more](http://www.topsharepoint.com/content-migration-tools-for-sharepoint).

All of them will preserve the metadata and much, much more.

If you want to use Powershell, you'll need to leverage the [SPFile.MoveTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470204.aspx) method.

You can also use the Site Content and Structure tool from Site Settings. It can also be activated directly via http://{YOURSITENAME}/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx

Comment: but I do not have any metadata ... I only want to move my root site and lists

Comment: Metadata is any data about data, so Created, Modified, Createdby and ModifiedBy which you wish to preserve is also metadata. These values being updated when you move content, is how SharePoint was designed. It has always worked like that. You can do it through Powershell by using the .SystemUpdate() method, but honestly it's easier to just use a migration tool.

Comment: so none of the available  features within sharepoint allow me to move a root site to be as a subsite ?? as i did not use these tools before,, and i am searching for a quick solution..

Comment: You could move the two lists you're interested in to a subside using the Site Content and Structure tool, but no, there is no out of the box way to move a root site to a subside.

Comment: you mean the Site Content and Structure tool allow me to move the whole list ?? or it allow me to move the documents inside them? and will it preserve the documents metadata?